# Dynamic Class Loading - Java

Tags: java

I am trying to create a program that will search a specified directory for any other jar files (which I will not know the name of).  It will then take the object from that file and create an instance of it that can be referenced later in my program.

I am happy to do the research on how to do this on my own, but do not know what this would be called to even start looking.

Anyone able to point me in the correct direction? Thanks

Comment: Check out the examples mentioned in this post http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/dynamic-class-loading-reloading.html

Comment: I do this in my project right now. Its rather easy using reflection. Check out the links people have been posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found a link that has a great example in it that is what helped me get it working the most.  Find it [Here](http://www.java-forums.org/advanced-java/25443-dynamic-class-loading-external-jar.html)

Answer (score 1):

You should google up `java reflection` and read some articles / samples upon it.

One good start would be:

- [Take an in-depth look at the Java
  Reflection API](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-09-1997/jw-09-indepth.html), then
- [Using Java Reflection](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/) and
- [Java – Dynamic loading of class and
  jar file](http://twit88.com/blog/2007/10/04/java-dynamic-loading-of-class-and-jar-file/)

Answer (score 0):

I faced problem of loading classes while working on a trading application and found following link useful.
http://trading.aurorasolutions.org/reflection-dynamically-loading-classes/

Comment: Please add some context for the link.

Answer (score -1):

IO:

```
File class
```

Reading Jar:

```
JarInputStream class
```

Loading classes, creating instances and calling methods:

```
ClassLoader class
Class class
Method class
```

Comment: Could you offer a little more explanation with your response?